# keep a function active for a specific time and if the the condition is true - end the look \ function

Tags: c#

this is abit messy so sorry about that,

i am new to C# so my question might be stupid, again sorry about that.

what i want to accomplished is something like that:

```
            private void RivalAlive()
        // The Function Should be alive for 10min - if the condition is performed then the function need to die (quit) immediately, also if the 10min has passed without the condition beeing performed the function will die.
        {
            if (SmallHour == 5) // if condition is performed it need to execute the code in the condition and quit the function
            //Run Another Function Here
            //End the RivalAlive Function
        {
        }
            //If the Condition is False - keep with the loop every 1 sec till 10min has passed
        }
```

thanks alot!

Comment: Why in the world do you want to keep the function "alive", so to speak? Is it just that you want to keep __polling__ for the value of SmallHour for the next 10 minutes?

Comment: yes, becouse the value can change every second (get updated via live gameserver), and if it is changing i need to run the reward function - but also kill the "RivalAlive" function so ppl wont abuse it and get double reward etc.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you just want to poll for the value of SmallHour for the next 10 minutes, here's the function:

```
private void RivalAlive()
{
    DateTime S = DateTime.Now;

    while(DateTime.Now.Subtract(S).TotalSeconds < 600 && SmallHour !=5)
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if(SmallHour == 5)
         EnterYourFunction();
}
```

This function will check the value of SmallHour every one second for the next 10 minutes. If the value is 5, it will quit. Otherwise it will quit after 10 minutes automatically.

Comment: but where do i enter the function i do want to run if SmallHour == 5?

Comment: thanks alot :), i need to call RivalAlive function by thread? i mean like that? new Thread(RivalAlive).Start();

Comment: @Dan272: I can only see a very small portion of your context, but I can smell that things like this would either run as a separate thread, process or even as a service.

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct to keep running the while loop for a ten minutes, instead you should implement Observer pattern to avoid unnecessary processor cycles.

Some object is keeping track of "SmallHour" and updating it. That object will be an Observable object, and all the other objects will register so that they can receive info about the update. In your case Observer is the object that contains RivalAlive() method. When observable object updates "SmallHour" it will notify all the observers in his list. Once the Observer does it's job it can unregister from the Observable and "die", or what ever logic you have in mind.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Check out the observer pattern on google.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx
(probably there are better examples than the one from this link)

EDIT:
I forgot about the condition that it needs to check for only ten minutes. It can store the time when it started to listen for a change. Once it receives an update of the SmallHour it can check if ten minutes have passed and act accordingly.